# Run Maven goal from Git Bash fail

Tags: java, git, bash, maven, testng

I configured my `pom.xml` for executing *TestNG suite* file.

Executed file is passed as to Maven as parameter.

But trouble is that when I run from console:

> mvn integration-test -Dmain-suite=${circuit-suite}

It works fine, test execution is started.

But when I tried to run it from `Git Bash` I got ***Error***:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.892 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-14T11:30:20+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/363M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) on project webClientI
MPAutomation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test failed: There was an e
rror in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file d:\HOME\IdeaProjects\webclient_suite\suite is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:83)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I couldn't investigate why it searches for `suite` as suite file.

Here is pom snippet:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <smoke-suite>${basedir}/src/test/resources/webClientIMPSuites/SmokeSuiteCI.xml</smoke-suite>
        <circuit-suite>${basedir}/src/test/resources/webClientIMPSuites/CircuitUITests.xml</circuit-suite>
    </properties>

<build>        
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>${main-suite}</suiteXmlFiles>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>                                                     
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I passing testng suite file as parameter to Maven. Executable `suite` files are saved as properties for ***pom***. At this case its value is:

> ${basedir}/src/test/resources/webClientIMPSuites/CircuitUITests.xml

***Why this strange behavier happens?***
How to solve it. And make execution at `Git Bash` too.

Comment: What is the value of ${circuit-suite} in your shell (commandline) ?

Comment: @WalterA it is pom property - `${basedir}/src/test/resources/webClientIMPSuites/CircuitUITests.xml`

Comment: I thought you was overruling it with the commandline `mvn integration-test -Dmain-suite=${circuit-suite}`.

Comment: @WalterA I explisitly saying which propery I pass as `main-suite`. This suite file is saved as pom properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a shell/command line variable `circuit-suite` which expands to `d:\HOME\IdeaProjects\webclient_suite\suite`. Try

```
mvn integration-test -Dmain-suite=\${circuit-suite}
```

Note the backslash before the `$`. This tells BASH to leave this variable alone and just pass it to Maven.